# Display Link to Category out of X Categories

Tags: categories

My first question ever ;-)

I have X Categories and I want to display the Link (with the name) but only if it is out of a list of Y Categories. So the code I am looking for is like this:

Show Link but only if the post is in one of the following Categories (Example: 1,5,88).

Here an example for better understanding:

- Category 1: New York
- Category 5: Miami
- Category 88: Toronto

The post is in Category 5.

Then I want to display:

——

City: **(Link)Miami(/Link)**

——

Thank you so much!